# What does the bitwise negation operator(\) do in prolog?

Tags: prolog, logic

I have to implement some functions, one of which is f= ~p/\~q.

I have the following :

```
p(a). p(b).
q(a). q(b). q(c).
```

I found the function as:

```
f(X):-p(\X);q(\X).
```

When I verify it ( f(X). , f(a). , f(b). , f(c). ) it always returns false.

Shouldn't it return true for c since c is not of type p?

Thank you!

Comment: It's not bitwise negation. It's bitwise COMPLEMENT. `f(a)` returns false, for example, because, as @false points out in his answer, the backslash in this context is acting like an uninterpreted functor. So neither `p(\a)` is a fact, nor is `q(\a)`. Therefore, `p(\a) ; q(\a)` fails. For backslash to do bitwise complement, it must be used with `is/2` or a numeric comparator, *e.g.*, `X = 1, Y is \X.` yields `Y = -2` (using @false's example), since `1` is `00000001` in hex and `-2` is `FFFFFFFE` in hex (assuming 32-bit words).

Comment: @mbratch: Assuming 2s complement.

Comment: @false yes, sorry, I should have mentioned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(\)/1` is an evaluable functor for bitwise complement. If you use it directly in an argument, it is only an uninterpreted functor. Evaluation is only performed with `(is)/2`, `(>)/2` and other comparison operators.

In all current Prolog implementations you get:

```
?- X is \ 1.
   X = -2.
```

<sub>Fine print: An ISO conforming system is free to define the value for `\`. That is, it is free, whether it uses 2's complement or another representation. However, there are only systems that use 2's complement.</sub>

Comment: @Slim_Shady: It is the bitwise complement with 2s complement.

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation of that formula seems flawed.

You are required about `f : (not p) and (not q)`

A restricted negation is available in Prolog, using operator `(\+)/1`, and conjunction (X and Y) is expressed by comma i.e. `(,)/2`.

Semicolon i.e. `(;)/2` means `or`, as for instance in the following test, that shows your initial assumption about `f(c)` is also wrong.

```
?- forall(member(X,[a,b,c,d]),(f(X)->writeln(y);writeln(n))).
n
n
n
y
```

(of course, after f/1 has been translated correctly)

Comment: the not(...) implementation is what I initially did..and it worked as one would expect.. but my teacher said it was not good.. that I should replace `not(p(X))` with `p(\X)`. Thank you for the explanation though!

Comment: I don't understand... You cannot apply \ operator to an atom. Then you should reify both p/1 and q/1. Totally useless.